# How can I best add additional fields to the Address form during the checkout

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, php, plugin-craftcommerce2, models, addresses

I want my customers to enter their **date of birth** and **place of birth** during the checkout.

Do I have to overwrite the Address commerce model somehow? (`\craft\commerce\models\Address`).

Something else I could think of is adding custom fields to the user itself. Though I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that date and place of birth would be more appropriate as custom fields on the User profile rather than attached to the address. They don't appear to have any relevance to an address, unless there's a very particular use-case you're building for.

Comment: The user orders a course for either themselves or someone else. This requires a date of birth and place of birth. This can differ per order so it made sense to put it in the Address but is not required. A profile field would be less favorable.

Comment: Ah. In that case, the data for date and place of birth are relevant to the order itself so I'd add them to the product/variant that's used for the course, rather than the address.